# Selecting features highly correlated with target while preserving low inter-correlation

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, scikit-learn, weka

I wonder if `sklearn` has any feature selection mechanism that chooses features that are highly correlated with target variable and maintains low inter-correlation among them. I know there is one in Weka, called `CfsSubsetEval`. I wonder if there is any equivalent method in `sklearn`. I have checked but could not see any relevant methods in this [URL](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html). I appreciate any help!